# With only rudimentary prior programming experience, exactly how would I begin creating a 3d top-down game using unity3D?

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, top-down

If possible please provide the documentation I need to get started. I need to get to the nitty gritty of things because I've gone through several languages and am ready to just start doing stuff.

In addition how exactly does one go about integrating bbcode editors into a webpage as the start of a forum site?

Comment: Short answer: You don't.

Comment: To be honest, you start with getting more than rudimentary programming experience.

Comment: Take a class. Than take more classes.

Comment: You guys always say that. Stop being so pessimistic. If other people can do this so can I. I'd also like to define "rudimentary" as having gone through a couple of c++ tutorials and reading up. I also have experience in javascript, jquery, and markup languages.

Comment: @efl They're not being pessimistic. They're being realistic. Everyone who does "advanced" programming first has to learn "basic" programming. So, start at the _beginning_; you're trying to start at the end. _Don't be in such a rush_.

Comment: Every time I read up on this stuff its a bunch of people telling people to start at the beginning. Where is the beginning? Where is the magical rainbow of programming I can ride to get "advanced programming experience"?

Comment: Based on your clarification of what you mean by  "rudimentary", you're lacking practical experience. Since you're keen on games, try writing a game of Tic-Tac-Toe or Connect Four. Make sure you learn to use your debugger, work with algorithms, and can work with your abstracted model of the game "board".

Answer (score 2):

You won't like my answer, but you will need to watch a tutorial (or several) on Unity3D. There are a lot of concepts/tools in their software that programming won't teach you.

Once you understand the fundamentals of Unity, the answer should become clear. You will create your scene, and then place a camera that is fixed downward on the Y axis. Attach it to your Gameobject of choice and you'll get camera movement baked in (to some degree).

Comment: Actually, I very much liked your answer. The rest of the people who answer these questions tell me I can't do it.